# Is it wise or not wise to to store View Model objects in NoSQL databases?

Tags: wpf, database, mvvm, nosql

I have say the following View Model in my WPF application.

```
public class User : ViewModelBase
{
 public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

 public int Age { get { return _age; } set { _age = value; OnPropertyChanged("Age"); } }
}
```

Now this information will be stored and pulled from a NoSQL database. My question is, should I keep separate Class in my project for the purpose of storage and retrieval to and from a NoSQL database and once the information is retrieved, build View Model or just using the View Model with NoSQL would be fine, surely that approach will save a lot of hassle.

What is the recommended way in NoSQL community in this regard ?

Comment: this is a very subjective question. But to answer the question if you did persist and bind the above ViewModel where is the Model in this MVVM implementation, it appears to me you don't have a Model. If you did have a Model you would be looking to persist this not the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

there are many different approaches to this, and it doesn’t really matter if you store the object in an RDBMS, NoSQL or some webservice which can again do what it wants.

it is true, that it’s easier if you don’t have to create a viewmodel - up to a certain point. Often you will find that extending the model by additonal properties which are only valid for your WPF implementation, and binding those properties, is easier than creating templates with different conditions. One example I have in mind would be for instance Color-Codes on your view, or if you have additional texts you want to display.

Those information can’t be in the original Model, because it isn’t relevant for anything else than your client. We’ve solved it in one project by annotating these properties with `[XmlIgnore]` - this way they weren’t serialized when talking to the server and we didn’t have to create an additional ViewModel. You might find that something like this is enough for you.

On the other hand for Web Applications, when serializing data with JSON it’s also important that you don’t want to send too much information to the client. Here it’s hard (sometimes not really possible) to adjust some autogenerated class definitions in order to annotate them appropriately. In thise case your only choice is to create special ViewModels and copy the data from one to the other.

In the end there comes one more factor - You might want to (or maybe rather, should) split your DataAccess logic from the rest. This way, if you decide to use a different storage mechanism you only need to reimplement that part, and make sure that your new Models can be transformed into the established ViewModels, so you don’t need to change everything.

You have to decide now for yourself - how fixed is your DataAccess infrastructure, will there ever change anything and are Annotations enough in order to hide additional information necessary for WPF bindings from your datastore? Or do you need a seperation between the Model and a ViewModel